# Agregar mas valores a función Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una funcion Jquery la cual me trae dos valores, el problema que necesito que me traiga mas de dos valores, ya he intentado algunas cosas y no ha funcionado.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    cargaProducto();

    jQuery("#ica").change(function() {
        cargaProducto();
    });
});

function cargaProducto() {

    if (jQuery("#ica").children(":selected").val() != 0) {
        jQuery.get("<?php echo url_for('productos/VerProductosIca?ica='); ?>" + jQuery("#ica").children(":selected").val(),
            function(data) {

                var prods = <?php echo json_encode($prods) ?>;

                jQuery("#producto").empty();
                jQuery.each(data, function(key, val, val2, val3) {
                    var select = "";
                    if (prods.includes(key))
                        select = 'selected="selected"';
                    //jQuery("#producto").append('<option value="' + key + '" ' + select + '> ' + key + ' - ' + val + ' </option>');
                    jQuery("#producto").append('<tr>' + '<td>' + key + '</td>' + '<td>' + val + '</td>' + '<td>' + val2 + '</td>' +

                    '<td>' + 

                     + '</td>' +

                     '</tr>');
                });
            }
        );
    } else {
        jQuery("#producto").empty();
        jQuery("#producto").append('<br>' + '<div class="alert alert-danger" value="0">Por favor seleccione un ICA o precione el boton QUITAR FILTOS para volver a los productos principales</div>');

    }
}
```

El código solo me trae los valores de key y val, lo que quiero hacer es que si agrego un val2 o val3 también me traiga esos valores de los nuevos val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en php, debes crear un array algo asi:

```
$variable = [    
    [
        "key"  => "Producto1",
        "val" => "valor2",
        "val2" => "valor3",
        "val3" => "valor3",
    ],
    [
        "key"  => "Producto1",
        "val" => "valor2",
        "val2" => "valor3",
        "val3" => "valor3",
    ]
]
```

Y en la parte de jQuery, debes hacer el each de esta manera:

```js
const data = [{
  key : "Producto1",
  val : "valor2",
  val2 : "valor3",
  val3 : "valor4"
},
{
  key : "Producto2",
  val : "valor2",
  val2 : "valor3",
  val3 : "valor4"
}
]

//El each de jquery funciona con 2 parámetros, el primero es el index y el segundo el objeto.

$.each(data, function (i, row){
   console.log(row.key, row.val, row.val2, row.val3)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Te recomiendo comprender como funciona Javascript primero antes de pasarte a usar jQuery, de igual manera Vanilla Javascript ya tiene todas las funcionalidades de jQuery.